# Why can't I break into a running test with the pdb interactive debugger?

Tags: python, django, testing, pdb

How can I break into a running test with the pdb interactive debugger?

This is the test:

```
class UserTestCase(TestCase):
  def test_register_should_create_UserProfile(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/account/register/', {u'username': [u'john'], u'email': [u'john@beatles.com'], u'bnewaccount': [u'Signup']})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    user = User.objects.get( username ='john')
    self.assertTrue(user.get_profile())
```

When I attempt to run the tests:
$ python manage.py test

The test database is created. The progress dots '.' begin to progress across the screen as the tests pass. 
Then the progess stops.

I am never shown a pdb> prompt in the terminal window.

How can I get pdb to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ipdb instead of vanilla pdb? I use ipdb and what you're trying to do works fine.

Alternatively, as a fallback, why not try the pdb call inside the method you're testing, just before the response is returned?

Comment: There should be zero difference between ipdb and pdb in the example usage.  They should both work just fine.  I would have started by moving the import to the first line of the test instead of by switching tools.  Switching tools may be masking a different problem.